# How do I use a GLM with longitudinal data to get a treatment effect at a specific time point in Stata?

Tags: stata, glm, longitudinal, mixed

So I want to use the mixed command. I have 3 different time points. I want to do a regression at time point 3 to see the effect of 'group' on 'score'. I tried to create a variable for score when time=3 (score3). Obviously this has a lot of missing data points as it's only got a number when time=3. Then I tried use the mixed command with score3 as the outcome i.e.

'''

mixed score3 group time || id:, mle

'''

Stata said it couldn't run this because there were too many missing data points in score3.

What do I do?

Comment: This seems more of a statistical problem to me, but it isn't clear without a data example.  You're asking us to imagine your data. The mix of statistics and Stata to me implies that you would be much better off asking this on Statalist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a straightforward programming problem, being more statistical, and it is too incomplete to recommend migration to Cross Validated.